# Reposition whole GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a `GridBagLayout` which is inside a `JPanel`, but is centered dead in the middle of it.

[image: The whole area is a JPanel]

Essentially, what im trying to do is keep the arrangement the same, but have it moved to where the red arrow is pointing (or even a bit lower). Here is some of the code I wrote:

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

...make all the JLabels/RadioBtns..

GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc1.anchor=GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
gbc1.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

gbc1.gridy=0;
gbc1.gridx=0;
add(title, gbc1);

gbc1.gridx=0;
gbc1.gridy=1;
add(block, gbc1);

..add more components
```

Comment: `GridBagLayout` by default, will centre all the components around the middle of the container.  You can use `weightx` and `weighty` to change how any given component fills it's cell with the remaining space within the container and using a simple "empty" filler component positioned off to the right/below of the other components will give the desired effect.  A `JLabel` without any text can work well here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is almost always caused by not setting the GridBagConstraints.weightx and GridBagConstraints.weighty properties correctly. Their default value is 0, which tells the components to bunch up in the center with a near preferredSize size. Give them both 1.0 on all components and watch what happens.

```
GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc1.anchor=GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
gbc1.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

//  ***** add: *****
gbc1.weightx = 1.0;
gbc1.weighty = 1.0;
```

This tells the layout to expand in both the x and y directions if the grid bag cell has room to expand.

If this doesn't help, then you'll want to create and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

One more thing: often the best most pleasing layout is achieved if you let all components strive to reach their preferredSize, and this is best done by avoiding calling `setSize(...)` or `setPreferredSize(...)` on most components, but rather simply calling `pack()` on the top level window before displaying it.

---

**Edit**
In comment you state:

> I have tried this before. It does align the layout into the top right corner, but it also scatters the components across the Panel. Im looking to keep the same clustering. I want all the labels and radiobtns to be close by (like in the pic)

Then what you want to do is use and nest at least **two** JPanels, the first using GridBagLayout and holding your GUI components as shown above, and the 2nd holding the first GridBagLayout-using JPanel. This 2nd JPanel could use BoxLayout, or FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT), or a bunch of other possible layouts or combinations of layouts.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GridBagLayoutEg extends JPanel {
    private static final Insets INSETS = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 600;

    public GridBagLayoutEg() {
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        innerPanel.add(new JLabel("Sequence name: abcdc"), createGbc(0, 0));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = createGbc(1, 0);
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        innerPanel.add(new JLabel(), gbc);

        innerPanel.add(new JLabel("Block making alighment tool:", SwingConstants.LEFT), createGbc(0, 1));
        innerPanel.add(new JRadioButton("Mafft"), createGbc(1, 1));
        innerPanel.add(new JRadioButton("Muscle"), createGbc(2, 1));
        innerPanel.add(new JRadioButton("ClusteIO"), createGbc(3, 1));

        innerPanel.add(new JLabel("Select Codon Table:", SwingConstants.LEFT), createGbc(0, 2));
        innerPanel.add(new JRadioButton("Standard"), createGbc(1, 2));
        innerPanel.add(new JRadioButton("Custom"), createGbc(2, 2));
        innerPanel.add(new JLabel(), createGbc(3, 2));

        innerPanel.add(new JLabel("Strictness:", SwingConstants.LEFT), createGbc(0, 3));
        innerPanel.add(new JTextField(2), createGbc(1, 3));

        innerPanel.add(new JLabel("Degeneracy:", SwingConstants.LEFT), createGbc(0, 4));
        innerPanel.add(new JTextField(2), createGbc(1, 4));

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 0, 0));
        add(innerPanel);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.insets = INSETS;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        return gbc;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayoutEg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new GridBagLayoutEg());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this before. It does align the layout into the top right corner, but it also scatters the components across the Panel. Im looking to keep the same clustering. I want all the labels and radiobtns to be close by (like in the pic)

Comment: @OrangePot: ah, then you need to *nest* JPanels to achieve this. Please see edit to answer.

Comment: @OrangePot: for example, please see code added in edit.